# Create overlay div wthout effecting the top div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website in which i am trying to make an overlay div entire to the body part when i hover the menu .

```
<header><menu><ul><li class="new-menu">menu1</li></menu></header>

 <div id="myNav" class="overlay"></div>

 <section id="content"></section>
```

This is my sample html code . in which header section contain menu,submeu etc .Body section contain other part.

```
 .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.58);

}
```

Here when i hover the new-menu i write code for to make `width of overlay 100%` . So that entire website get black overlay.

But i only want to give overlay to section (#content) part. How i can achieve this?

Even i am using css top property but it is not work well because my  menu is sticky header

Answer (score 1):

Try to give position fixed for your sticky header.

**Example:**

```
<header><menu><ul><li class="new-menu">menu1</li></menu></header>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay"></div>

<section id="content"></section>
```

**CSS:**

```
header{
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.58);
}
```

```css
header{
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.58);
}
```

```html
<header><menu><ul><li class="new-menu">menu1</li></menu></header>

 <div id="myNav" class="overlay"></div>

 <section id="content"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use after or before to make overlay on specific div

```
#content{position:relative}
 #content:After{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0;background:#000;content: '';}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
header:hover + #myNav {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding an explanation with the code. This has been flagged as low quality.